# root-logger level and console-handler level

Tags: logging, wildfly

my standalone.xml setting is as follow:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0">
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <!--<level name="INFO"/>-->
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
</console-handler>
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
<logger category="com.arjuna">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="io.jaegertracing.Configuration">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
<logger category="sun.rmi">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<root-logger>
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
        <handler name="FILE"/>
    </handlers>
</root-logger>
<formatter name="PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
</formatter>
<formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
</formatter>
```

and in my Class EXM010,

```
private final static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(EXM010.class);
public void method1(){
     logger.debug("see debug?");
     logger.info("see info?");
```

1) I find if root-logger level is "INFO", then even console-handler level is "DEBUG", the "see debug?" is not shown, I must set `<root-logger><level name="DEBUG"/>` for the "see debug?" message to show, why?

2) If I set root-logger level to "DEBUG", then too many wildfly debug message to show....any method to let wildfly debug message level to "INFO", just my class EXM010 or my application code level to "DEBUG"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a logger which you set to the debug level for your logger. For example if you're class name is `org.example.EXM010.class` you'd need to add a logger like:

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.example.EXM010:add(level=DEBUG)
```

If you have more debug messages for the same package you want to see you could just add the `org.example` logger.

It's best to use CLI or the web management console to do this. You won't need to restart or reload the server when you add or edit a logger this way.

Comment: then what is the use of <Console-handler name="CONSOLE"> <level name="DEBUG"/>? seem it does not see this setting...

Comment: You would have to change the level of the console handler to debug as well. But since the root logger is set to INFO that sets any undefined loggers to INFO. So you need to define the logger and say you want those messages logged at debug.